# How to trigger AWS Events Rule only when a specific file (key) gets written to an S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-step-functions

I am trying to make an AWS Event (in CloudWatch or EventBridge) that triggers the run of an AWS Step Function when a specific file is put into an S3 Bucket.

My event pattern for the Rule is shown below:

```json
{
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "PutObject"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": [
        "bucketname"
      ],
      "key": [
        "date={{TODAYS DATE}}/_SUCCESS"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Optimally I would like to have the `key` element pointing to a path where `TODAYS DATE` represents the current date and `_SUCCCESS` is an empty file printed to the directory by the my job once it has successfully completed (e.g. if today was 10/31/2019 the full bucket path to check would be `bucketname/date=20191031/_SUCCESS`).  The end goal is to have the Event Rule triggering a Step Function which controls a number of other daily jobs that can only run once the first job that outputs the `_SUCCESS` file to the bucket has completed successfully.

Preferably I would like to have the key check for the `_SUCCESS` file using that day's current date.  However, if there is no good way to deal with the dates I should also be able to make something work if there is a way to trigger the Rule once when a new directory is put into the bucket (e.g. trigger when directory `date=XXXXXX` is created).  I just cannot have the trigger activate each time any new file is put into the bucket as the initial job will create a number of output files in the `date=XXXXXX` directory which are used as input for the following jobs.

It would also be very helpful to be able to create this Rule via AWS CloudFormation, so if CloudFormation has any way to deal with these issues that would be great.

Thank you in advance for any help, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understand what you are trying to achieve here but why don't you just subscribe lambda function to the bucket where your files are being stored (subscribe it put event), do whatever kind of checks you want to perform programatically inside of that lambda function and if all the conditions are met, just call the mentioned step function from within the lambda function.

And if any of the condition is not met then simply don't launch the step function.

Here is how you can subscribe lambda function to S3 put event (via web console).

1. go to S3
2. pick your bucket
3. go to `Properties tab`
4. select `Events`
5. check `PUT` event
6. under `Send to`, pick `Lambda Function`
7. pick existing lambda function (you need to create that lambda function)

**How to access properties such as bucket name, object key and timestamp of the event from within the lambda function. (using Python)**

```
def handler_name(event, context): 
    // get bucket name
    print(event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'])

    // get object key
    print(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])

    // get event timestamp
    print(event['Records'][0]['eventTime'])

    return 0
```

Here is complete `event` object (S3 event object that is) for reference.

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.1",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
      "eventTime": "2019-09-03T19:37:27.192Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "AWS:AIDAINPONIXQXHT3IKHL2"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "205.255.255.255"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "D82B88E5F771F645",
        "x-amz-id-2": "vlR7PnpV2Ce81l0PRw6jlUpck7Jo5ZsQjryTjKlc5aLWGVHPZLj5NeC6qMa0emYBDXOo6QBU0Wo="
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "828aa6fc-f7b5-4305-8584-487c791949c1",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "lambda-artifacts-deafc19498e3f2df",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "A3I5XTEXAMAI3E"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::lambda-artifacts-deafc19498e3f2df"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "b21b84d653bb07b05b1e6b33684dc11b",
          "size": 1305107,
          "eTag": "b21b84d653bb07b05b1e6b33684dc11b",
          "sequencer": "0C0F6F405D6ED209E1"
        }
      }
    }

  ]
}
```

**How to execute Step Function from within Lambda Function (using Python + Boto3)**

```
import boto3

sfn_client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')

def handler_name(event, context): 

    response = sfn_client.start_execution(
        stateMachineArn='string',
        name='string',
        input='string'
    )

    return 0
```

where `stateMachineArn` is the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the state machine to execute, `name` (optional) is name of the execution and `input` is the string that contains the JSON input data for the execution.

Comment: What do you mean by subscribe the lambda function to a put event? Is there a way to use a lambda function similarly to a CloudWatch event where you can have it constantly watching a certain location in an S3 bucket waiting to trigger an event when the proper condition is met? Also, how would you go about writing a lambda function to watch for a put event or trigger a step function? Sorry, I am kind of new to this.

Comment: Yes, all of that is possible. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! One last question, do you know if it is possible to set up the events/ create the lambda functions tied to the buckets like that using CloudFormation? I will need to have this process running over a number of buckets in a number of regions and it would be much cleaner and more manageable to have a CloudFormation template handling this rather than having to go through doing a bunch of manual edits in a bunch of areas every time I need to make an update.

Comment: Yes you can do that via CF. S3 bucket has an attribute `NotificationConfiguration` under which you can specify `LambdaConfiguration` - event type (PUT) and the Lambda function to be executed.

Comment: I am having trouble getting AWS CloudFormation to accept my template to set up this trigger (see my recent edit to the main question).  I keep getting an `Unrecognized resource types` error on the `Type:` line, do you know what needs to go on this line?

Comment: You should revert the changes that you have made and start a new question instead  because we will turn the original one into something completely different which is not really useful to any future visitors. But to shortly answer your question, you are doing it wrong. The configuration is performed under S3 bucket in CF, not under that ad-hoc type. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html and there you can find the above mentioned types and how to use them.

Comment: For the sake of better organization I separated my follow up into its own question. Please see the link here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58739265/set-up-s3-bucket-level-events-using-aws-cloudformation