# Set up S3 Bucket level Events using AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to get AWS CloudFormation to create a template that will allow me to attach an event to an existing S3 Bucket that will trigger a Lambda Function whenever a new file is put into a specific directory within the bucket.  I am using the following YAML as a base for the CloudFormation template but cannot get it working.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  SETRULE:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: bucket-name
        NotificationConfiguration:
          LambdaConfigurations: 
            - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:Put
              Filter: 
                S3Key:
                  Rules:
                    - Name: prefix
                      Value: directory/in/bucket
              Function: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXX:function:lambda-function-trigger
              Input: '{ CONFIGS_INPUT }'
```

I have tried rewriting this template a number of different ways to no success.

Comment: What's the error you getting?

Comment: have you added the permissions for lambda invocation on your S3 bucket?

Comment: I have gotten a few different errors depending on the slight alterations I have been making, most recently I got a `YAML not well-formatted` error on the line that just reads `Properties:`.  And the lambda function is defined normally under the lambda functions service in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned that those buckets already exists, this is not going to work. You can use CloudFormation in this way but only to create a new bucket, not to modify existing bucket if that bucket was not created via that template in the first place.

If you don't want to recreate your infrastructure, it might be easier to just use some script that will subscribe lambda function to each of the buckets. As long as you have a list of buckets and the lambda function, you are ready to go.

Here is a script in Python3. Assuming that we have:

1. 2 buckets called **test-bucket-jkg2** and **test-bucket-x1gf**
2. lambda function with arn: **arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:605189564693:function:my_func**

There are 2 steps to make this work. First, you need to add function policy that will allow s3 service to execute that function. Second, you will loop through the buckets one by one, subscribing lambda function to each one of them.

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client("s3") 
lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')

buckets = ["test-bucket-jkg2", "test-bucket-x1gf"]
lambda_function_arn = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:605189564693:function:my_func"

# create a function policy that will permit s3 service to 
# execute this lambda function

# note that you should specify SourceAccount and SourceArn to limit who (which account/bucket) can
# execute this function - you will need to loop through the buckets to achieve 
# this, at least you should specify SourceAccount
try:
    response = lambda_client.add_permission(
        FunctionName=lambda_function_arn,
        StatementId="allow s3 to execute this function",
        Action='lambda:InvokeFunction',
        Principal='s3.amazonaws.com'
        # SourceAccount="your account",
        # SourceArn="bucket's arn"
    )
    print(response)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# loop through all buckets and subscribe lambda function 
# to each one of them
for bucket in buckets:
    print("putting config to bucket: ", bucket)
    try:
        response = s3_client.put_bucket_notification_configuration(
            Bucket=bucket,
            NotificationConfiguration={
                'LambdaFunctionConfigurations': [
                    {
                        'LambdaFunctionArn': lambda_function_arn,
                        'Events': [
                            's3:ObjectCreated:*'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        )
        print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: It is also important that I am able to trigger this and pass a set of cluster config inputs to the triggering lambda function.  The lambda function will trigger a state machine that uses that input to spin up an EMR cluster. I would preferably be able to set this using CloudFormation so a CloudFormation update could send the changes to be used next time the event is triggered. Do you know how to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't understand. CloudFormation is just IaaC (description of your environment). `CloudFormation update could send the changes to be used next time the event is triggered?` What kind of changes and send them to where? Some kind of even would trigger CF update? In what way and how would that event modify template? Are you planning to build your template programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom resource to do this, in fact that's what I've ended up doing at work for the same problem. At the simplest level, define a lambda that takes a put bucket notification configuration and then just calls the put bucket notification api with the data that was passed it.

If you want to be able to control different notifications across different cloudformation templates, then it's a bit more complex. Your custom resource lambda will need to read the existing notifications from S3 and then update these based on what data was passed to it from CF.